# Updating data in a XML file in marklogic using java api

Tags: hadoop, marklogic

Say I inserted XML file in MarkLogic datastore:

```
<Providers>
    <Provider>
        <UniqueId>1111</UniqueId>
        <name>John Doe</name>
        <Age>40</Age>
        <Country>MN</Country>
    </Provider>
    <Provider>
        <UniqueId>2222</UniqueId>
        <name>Johny Deep</name>
        <Age>51</Age>
        <Country>NY</Country>
    </Provider>
</Providers>
```

Now if I want to update the name to 'Jane Doe' where Unique Id is '1111', how can I achieve this using MarkLogic's java API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goel, it sounds like you need the [Patch operation](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/document-operations#id_46664). This allows you to specify a specific part of a document and add to, change, or delete it.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I tried something like this:               DocumentPatchHandle xmlPatch = xmlPatchBldr.replaceFragment(
          "/Providers/Provider[1]/name", 
          "Jane Doe")
        .build();                                                                                    It replaced the name, but i was not able to find out how to check for unique id. If you can help..

Comment: Your XPath specifies the first Provider. Instead, specify the one you want: `"/Providers/Provider[UniqueId = '1111']/name"`